# Another expression for 'being'

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I don't want to use the word 'being'.  How would you rephrase the following sentences?

- ***Instead of being*** a run down, derelict building, Coral Tower is positively vibrant.
- ***Far from being*** a sedentary person, Tyler climbs crags and dives into gorges for fun.

Comment: 1. Contrary to [a dilapidated building estate] XYZ is ... 2. Contrary to [a sedentary person] XYZ climbs, (etc.)

Comment: You could just remove the word 'being' and leave nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry....immediately after posting I thought of a couple of alternatives:

- **Far from** a run down, derelict building, Coral Tower is positively vibrant.
- **Unlike** run down, derelict buildings **in Hong Kong**, Coral Tower is positively vibrant.

Always thought 'being' was a rather weak and abstract word, after reading Elements of Style and Zinsser's *On Writing*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that 'being' is weak, but I'd have regarded 'far from being' as idiomatic and perhaps a reasonable choice of words. Without the word being, the far from phrase is a bit easy to misinterpret when reading; i.e Coral Tower is positively vibrant and physically a long way from that run down building over yonder.

A different introductory phrase, depending on what you are trying to convey, might be best:

- No longer a run down, derelict building ...
- hgst's Unlike run down ...